# Sending javascript code to external javascript file in kendo ui

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I'm trying to send all my js code from kendo grid to external file. But I can't do that, because js file cannot include razor syntax. How can I get my authors from controller method?

**My editor that use razor in datasource**

```
function authorsEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input name="Authors">').appendTo(container)
        .kendoMultiSelect({
            dataValueField: "AuthorId",
            dataTextField: "AuthorName",
            //this datasource works
            dataSource: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(LibraryApp.BLL.ViewModels.AuthorViewModel.GetAllAuthors))
            //this not, but wanna something like this
            dataSource: "/Home/GetAllAuthors" 
        });
}
```

I have the method in my controller that return authors from database.
How can I send them to datasource?

```
    public JsonResult GetAllAuthors()
    {
        var authors = bookService.GetAuthors();
        return Json(authors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

If something is not clear enough, ask questions)

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "I'm trying to send all my js code from kendo grid to external file", but I can understand "How can I send them to datasource?". The [kendo docs are pretty good](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datasource/remote-data-binding)

Comment: I mean that now all js code is in one view, but I want to put it in a separate file like myKendoScript.js. Js don't know anything about Razor, so Razor expression does not let me do it.

Comment: You shouldn't need a razor expression in the javascript. Where you feel you need it there should be a javascript variable or function call.

Comment: Thank you for your advance, i will read docs in a little while.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your link was very useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who also ask my question

**I changed my datasource to that:**

```
function authorsEditor(container, options) {
$('<input name="Authors">').appendTo(container)
    .kendoMultiSelect({
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Grid/GetAllAuthors",
                }
            }
        }),
        dataValueField: "AuthorId",
        dataTextField: "AuthorName",
    });
```

**Controller method:**

```
 public JsonResult GetAllAuthors()
    {
        var authors = bookService.GetAuthors();
        return Json(authors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**In views:**

```
<div id="grid"></div>

@section Scripts
{
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyKendoScripts/BookGridForAdmin.js")"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

.**CSHTML** (Write below code snippet in javascript block)

```
var dataMultiSelect = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(LibraryApp.BLL.ViewModels.AuthorViewModel.GetAllAuthors))';
$(document ).ready(function() { 
authorsEditor(null,null); // call your js function here - after data loading
});
```

**JS** File code

```
function authorsEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input name="Authors">').appendTo(container)
        .kendoMultiSelect({
            dataValueField: "AuthorId",
            dataTextField: "AuthorName", 
            dataSource: dataMultiSelect 
        });
}
//OR
function authorsEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input name="Authors">').appendTo(container)
        .kendoMultiSelect({
            dataValueField: "AuthorId",
            dataTextField: "AuthorName",  
            dataSource: JSON.parse(dataMultiSelect) -- converting string into JS array/object
        });
}
```